# Error creating context 'spring.root' inner exception: WebSupportModule not initialized

Tags: asp.net, spring, web-config

I have an ASP.NET web application which compiles and uses some references, like `Spring.Web`, `Spring.Core`, `Spring.Aop`, `Spring.Core` and `Spring.Services`. The corresponding *dlls* are in the `bin` folder. When I start the web application with Internet Explorer, I get this exception:

```
Error creating context 'spring.root': An exception occurred in the type initializer of 'Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.WebObjectFactory'.
the inner exception
TypeInitializationException: An exception occurred in the type initializer of 'Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.WebObjectFactory'.
ConfigurationErrorsException: WebSupportModule not initialized. Did you forget to add <add name = "Spring" type = "Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web" /> to your web.config's <httpModules> -section?
```

This is the related part of my *webConfig*

```
on httpModules><br>
 i put the add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/> <br>
 i put the add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>  <br>
 i put the add name="BRF" type="BRF.Core.Web.BRFHttpModule, BRF.Core.Web"/><br>
this is the end of httpModules> <br>
```

But i do it right, so i do not understaing why happends the exception.
What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Way too late for you but that will also be a reminder for my future self.

As you know in your `Web.config` you need to have this section

```xml
<httpModules>
    <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
</httpModules>
```

But you also need to have another section in that file

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
        <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```